# Exception : The signature verified correctly with the key contained in the signature, but that key is not trusted

Tags: c#, asp.net, identityserver3, sustainsys-saml2

I have setup the IdentityServer along with SustainSys Saml2 library. I am using metadata file generated from PingIdentity (IdP). It was working fine earlier. Recently they changed the certificate. So earlier the certificate was issued by some other provider and now the new certificate is generated by some other provider. So we asked for the updated metadata xml file and replaced it with the old one.

After doing this, when we try it throws following exception message. "The signature verified correctly with the key contained in the signature, but that key is not trusted"

I am using following configurations options.

```
            string configuredIdentityProviderEntityId = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IdentityProviderEntityId"];
            string configuredIdentityProviderMetaDataLocation = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IdentityProviderMetaDataLocation"];

            var options = new Saml2AuthenticationOptions(false)
            {
                SPOptions = new SPOptions
                {
                    EntityId = new EntityId(configuredEntityId),
                    MinIncomingSigningAlgorithm = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1",
                },
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = signInAsType,
                Caption = "SAML"
            };

            options.SPOptions.Compatibility.IgnoreAuthenticationContextInResponse = true;

            options.SPOptions.ServiceCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2(
                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase + "/App_Data/Sustainsys.Saml2.Tests.pfx"));
 options.IdentityProviders.Add(new IdentityProvider(
                new EntityId(configuredIdentityProviderEntityId),
                options.SPOptions)
            {
                LoadMetadata = true,
                MetadataLocation = configuredIdentityProviderMetaDataLocation
            });
```

We have already verified the certificate coming in response of SAML and the metadata file's certificate.

Both of them are matching.

What can be the possible issue ? Please guide.

Answer (score 3):

It worked, after changing the metadata file it was giving error. After recycling App Pool it started working fine.